# Dropzonejs remove files without calling remove callback

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzonejs to upload files to use in my module. The way it works is you edit an item, you drag a file to the dropzone, the dropzone hides and you see a preview of the image. That preview is self-made and has a delete button to delete the image and nullify the column in the database.

To delete the files, the dropzone has a `.on` call for `removedfile`. This is put in a global function looking something like this (only with the important data for the question):

```
function createDropzone(removeCallback, id) {
    $('#' + id).dropzone({
        url: 'URL TO UPLOAD FILE',
        init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;

            this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
                $.post('URL TO DELETE FILE', {file: file}, function(response) {
                    // handle delete
            } 
        },
    }
}
```

Now in this specific module when somebody uploads an image, it has to hide the dropzone element and show a custom preview element. However, if somebody wishes to delete the image, it has to remove the files from the dropzone AND run the click event when clicked on the delete icon by the custom preview.

The problem however is, if an image exists, it won't add the image to the dropzone and you will see the custom preview immediately. Thus, I cannot simply call the dropzone `removeallfiles` function, since the dropzone doesn't always contain the image. But when I call the `removeallfiles` function AND the event is called and an image is in the dropzone, it will try to remove the file twice.

Is there any way to remove all files from the dropzone without getting the `removedfiles` called?

(sorry if my explaination isn't well, it's still early in the morning, I can explain it better)

Comment: A https://stackblitz.com/ fiddle would be helpful in this case

Comment: Sorry I have been working on something else I thought would be much quicker and I wasn't in the office friday. I can't get DropzoneJS working on there with CDN on StackBlitz. Keeps giving me the error "$(...).dropzone is not a function"

Comment: A minimal git repo also will do

Comment: Oh damn, I feel really bad. I forgot about a check for a certain element I made in the remove callback which doesn't proceed to the AJAX call to remove the file if the element is nonexistent. Thus, I don't have to do it complicated, I can just delete the elements (which in this case is perfectly fine). Thanks anyways for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb, I had a check in the removeFiles callback already (in my original code) so that if a specific element doesn't exist, it won't execute the AJAX file.

```
this.on('removedfile', function (file) {
    if (file.previewTemplate.children[6]) {
            // $.POST CODE HERE
    }
}
```

This element is created in the `successmultiple` event like this:

```
previewTemplate.append('<input type="hidden" name="fileNames[]" value="' + ajaxResponse.filenames[i] + '">');
previewTemplate.append('<input type="hidden" name="extensions[]" value="' + ajaxResponse.extensions[i] + '">');
```

This way, when the element is removed, it won't go in the IF but still be removed from the dropzone. This way, you can remove all files from the dropzone without calling the remove file AJAX.

Comment: It's been 2 years so I'm not 100% sure, maybe previewTemplate was an object and children had a certain amount of entries already, and the element I needed was on index 6, that'd be just 100% a guess since I did do this 2 years ago so I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Dropzone's `addedfile`event to remove any non-final previous upload attempts, like this:

```
init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
        if (this.files.length > 1) {
            this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

Then on submit, I'm processing the files:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on("click", function (e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
    if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    }
});
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Not that it is necessary as I found a way to "fix" it, though I'm curious. The point is, `removeFile` calls the AJAX for deleting files if I'm correct, right? Because that was the whole problem. Thanks for your respond but it isn't really needed anymore, but I couldn't close it because of the bounty.